# Using Vimeo with Aframe

Tags: aframe, vimeo-api, webvr

I am attempting to get the vimeo plugin working with a-frame, but no success. I followed the GitHub steps at https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component -> I have a vimeo pro account, generated key, updated .env file, edited basic.html to show my video ID. When I attempt to play it, I just get a black screen. I also downloaded the aframe-vimeo-component.min.js locally and created a .env file in my base html folder, and same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Node.js server (i.e `yarn run start`)?

There is a [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component/wiki/Getting-Started-%F0%9F%9A%80#using-glitch) you can use that walks through all the options of using the component.

If you are not sure where to start, you can [remix the Glitch example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/aframe-vimeo-component), add your token to the *.env* file, and swap the `id` parameter [in the basic (`examples/basic.html`) example](https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component/blob/master/examples/basic.html#L10) to your Vimeo video id

Feel free to [open a Github issue](https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component/issues/new) if something isn't working properly so we can try and solve it